# Looking for matching strings of length > 4 between two text files

Tags: python

I'm trying to read in two text files, and then search each for strings that are common between the two, of minimum length 5.

The code I've written:

```
db = open("list_of_2","r").read()
lp = open("lastpass","r").read()

word = ''
length = 0

for dbchar in db:
    for lpchar in lp:
        if dbchar == lpchar:
            word += str(dbchar)
            length += 1
        else:
            length = 0
            word = ''
        if length > 4:
            print(word)
```

The code currently prints strings like '-----' and '55555', over and over and doesn't seem to break the loop (these particular strings only appear in `lp` once). I also don't believe it's finding strings that *aren't* just the same character repeated.

How do I alter the code to:

1. Only make it run through and print each occurrence once, and
2. Not just find strings of the same character repeated?

Edit: Here are some mock text files. In these, the string 'ghtyty' appears in file1 three times, and in file2 4 times. The code should print 'ghtyty' to console once.

[file1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BAUN7Ib0QRZ1_XM6ZxdesGziZ-mvqcY-)
[file2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hxgntFLkVfhF0KKnzWLBL2P9ZQEfs7R4)

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of text in both the files?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. One of the files contains my passwords with their associated domains. :)

Comment: You can invent some mock data which would enable you to offer a [mcve].

Comment: You could create harmless sample files nevertheless. Anyway, take a look at the `difflib` module (especially `SequenceMatcher`) which may help here.

Comment: Do the strings have special characteristics, like being only space separated words? Because that would make life so much easier.

Comment: Fair enough. I've added some dummy data to the original post.

Comment: They're both plain text files. I've changed the links and file extensions accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach. Split the files into words and keep only words 5 characters or greater. Use sets to find the intersection--this will be faster.

```
db_words = set([x for x in db.split() if len(x) > 4])
lp_words = set([x for x in lp.split() if len(x) > 4])

matches = db_words & lp_words
```

If you want to exclude words of all same character, you can define the list comprehension like this:

```
[x for x in db.split() if len(x) > 4 and x != x[0]*len(x)]
```

---

If you are looking for *any consecutive sequence* of characters that match, this might work better:

```
i_skip = set()  # characters to skip if they are already in a printed word
j_skip = set()

for i in range(len(db)-4):
    if i in i_skip: continue
    for j in range(len(lp)-4):
        if j in j_skip: continue
        if db[i] == lp[j]:
            word_len = 5
            while db[i:i+word_len] == lp[j:j+word_len]:
                if db[i:i+word_len+1] == lp[j:j+word_len+1]:
                    word_len += 1
                else:
                    print(db[i:i+word_len])
                    i_skip.update(range(i, i+word_len))
                    j_skip.update(range(j, j+word_len))
                    break
```

Comment: Doesn't split depend on predefined/known separators? Unfortunately neither file is arranged so neatly, and I'm looking for any match of 5 consecutive characters.

Comment: `split` will split using any whitespace. Is this not how you are defining words?

Comment: I've added some dummy data to the original post.